# iOS: Image blending with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-graphics, blending

I would like to blend two images using Core Graphics.

For example, I have an image:

[image]

This image represents the frame. I would like to have this image sliceable.

Another image represents the background:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve, is to blind those two images like:

[image]

The important thing, that this image might not necessary be circle. It might be sliceable.

How can I achieve this by using Core Graphics?

Comment: Is the core-graphics a requirement? Or you just want to show that image in `UIImageView`?

Comment: Basically, I need to show this in `UIImageView`. I listed Core Graphics to avoid third party dependencies.

Comment: then try my answer, I believe that is what you are looking for (it's called masking and not blending)

Comment: Masking should work, but that may depend on one thing - what is meant by "sliceable"?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, I have written you a comment. By saying slicing, I mean, that image will scale according to slices defined by asset.

Comment: @DaumantasVersockas how did you finish up solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following method that uses masking (`maskImage` is the one that represents "frame", so in your example it would be that black circle, surrounding of the black circle has to be transparent):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let imageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let cons = [
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(cons)

        setup(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image"), withMask: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "masking"))
    }

    fileprivate func setup(image: UIImage, withMask maskImage: UIImage) {
        imageView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        imageView.image = maskImage
        let slicedMask = captureView(imageView: imageView)
        imageView.image = image
        let mask = CALayer()
        mask.contents = slicedMask.cgImage
        mask.frame = imageView.bounds
        imageView.layer.mask = mask
    }

    func captureView(imageView: UIImageView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        imageView.layer.render(in: context)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}
```

I deal with slicing here quite "hacky": first I render the mask in the `imageView` to get it sliced, then I take a "screenshot" of the rendered sliced mask, and use the screenshot as a mask.

Keep in mind that `mask.frame = imageView.bounds` has to set frame properly, thus at that point the layout should be done. If later layout of the image changes, you will have to setup the mask again. `mask.frame` always have to fit the `imageView.bounds` (so if the layout changes in time, re-setup the image after layout changed).

Comment: Hey! I am sorry, but this solution doesn't work at all... When I add the code after setting the image, image becomes not visible at all...

Comment: @DaumantasVersockas This would happen if `mask.frame = imageView.bounds` sets the `mask.frame` to `CGSize.zero` - and that could happen if the `imageView.bounds` was zero. That could have happened if you use autolayout but the views have not been laid out yet. Before setting the frame of the mask call `imageView.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()` to make sure that the `mask`'s frame corresponds the final `imageView`'s bounds. I've updated the answer with an example that's working for me with the images that you included in your question.

Comment: It seems to work, except slicing. The mask image is not sliced according the slicing defined in asset

Comment: Yes, the slicing needs to be applied to mask image! :)

Comment: @DaumantasVersockas OK, I updated my answer, it seems to work, although I am not sure I understand how sliced images work in `UIImageView`  - but if you know, you should be able to make it work

Comment: @DaumantasVersockas Hi bro, did you manage to get it working?